# Filter the Results by Wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching for a keyword "foobar" and I want to filter by wildcard. I declared the field type for url as **keyword**.

```
Get /Some-index/_search    
{
        "query": {
            "wildcard" : { 
                "url" : { 
                    "value" : "http://www.abce/ghi/*", 
                    "boost" : 2.0 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented the below [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query using [Query and Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) context. Do refer to these links for more information.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "<your_field_name>":"foobar"
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "wildcard":{  
                        "url":{  
                           "value":"http://www.goo*",
                           "boost":2
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Kamal, Thanks for sharing. Its working for me. Is there any other way to filter the results apart from the wildcard in my case and if i declared field type as text for url field.

Comment: @an__snatcher I think what you have is good enough. Afaik `url` field is mostly used as a `keyword`. If you do convert it into `text`, you may want to execute the below and see how tokens are created, thereby create `regex` accordingly.

Comment: `GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "http://www.google.com/maps"
}` Hope it helps!